# Asp.net Get summary footer in grid view control

Tags: asp.net, gridview, footer, summary

I have a grid view control:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat ="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false" >                      
     <Columns>                                       
        <asp:BoundField  DataField ="Id" HeaderText ="Agreement ID"/>              
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="Balance" HeaderText ="Balance" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The code behind:

```
Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form1.Load
    Dim agreementManager As AgreementManager = New AgreementManager()
    Dim lstAgr As List(Of Agreement) = agreementManager.GetAll()
    grdView.DataSource = lstAgr
    grdView.DataBind()
End Sub
```

The output:

[image: GridViewOutput]

Then, I want to add a footer with the summary of balance like this:

[image]

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this, refer this solution :
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satyapriyanayak/dsfsdf/

For footer template for each column :

```
Dim total As Decimal = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Decimal)("Balance"))
grdView.FooterRow.Cells(0).Text = "Balance"
grdView.FooterRow.Cells(0).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
grdView.FooterRow.Cells(1).Text = total.ToString("Balance")
```

refer this example : [ASP.NET gridview footer template](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-sum-of-Columns-total-in-GridView-Footer-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Comment: That approach add new column to get the total balance, I want to see if is possible to  put the total summary  balance in the same column as the other balances.

Comment: I have updated my answer for footer for each column.